# Ruby Symbols vs Strings in Hashes

Tags: ruby, string, hash, symbols

I have this hash:

```
{
  "title"=>"Navy to place breath-test machines on all its ships", 
  "url"=>"http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/click.phdo?i=a67626ca64a9f1766b8ba425b9482d49"
}
```

It turns out that

```
hash[:url] == nil
```

and

```
hash['url'] == "http://feeds.washingtonpost.com/click.phdo?i=a67626ca64a9f1766b8ba425b9482d49"
```

Why? Shouldn't it work with either?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since a symbol is not the same as a string:

```
:url == 'url' #=> false
```

As hash keys they would be different. Perhaps you have seen this behavior in Rails? Ruby on Rails uses [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://apidock.com/rails/HashWithIndifferentAccess) which maps everything to a String internally, so you can do this:

```
h = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
h['url'] = 'http://www.google.com/'
h[:url] #=> 'http://www.google.com/'
```

Comment: It was Rails. Oh the life of learning Rails at the same time as Ruby.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but HashWithInDifferentAccess actually just checks if the key is a Symbol and coerces in into a String if that's the case, not the other way around https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3d6eafe32ed498784dba2b9782bbf7df47ebeb6b/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb#L152

Answer (score 4):

`:url` is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) which is different than the [String](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fcore%2FString.html&ei=YkNhT-PaIpO_gAeGmY3eAg&usg=AFQjCNFSy5kt8d57M00ZBJLEKScIM1_pTA) `'url'`

```
> :ruby == "ruby­"
=> false
```

You can convert back and forth between the two using `to_s` and `to_sym`

```
> "ruby".to_­sym
=> :ruby
> :ruby.to_s
=> "ruby"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why?---Because `:url` and `'url'` are different, i.e., `:url != 'url'`.

Shouldn't it work with either?---No.