# Parse output from bash script to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I have a bash script from another stackoverflow question to get all my serial connected devices:

```
#!/bin/bash
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && continue
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue
        echo "{name: '/dev/$devname', id_serial: '$ID_SERIAL'}"
    )
done
```

I am trying to parse them as an array of objects in order to iterate and display them on a Rails view. The output is this:

```
{name: '/dev/input/event16', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/input/mouse2', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/hidraw0', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/usb/hiddev3', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/input/event17', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/hidraw1', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}
{name: '/dev/input/event15', id_serial: 'SunplusIT_INC._Integrated_Camera'}
{name: '/dev/media0', id_serial: 'SunplusIT_INC._Integrated_Camera'}
{name: '/dev/video0', id_serial: 'SunplusIT_INC._Integrated_Camera'}
```

In Rails console this is the output:

```
2.2.4 :001 > `./lib/scripts/get_serial.sh`
 => "{name: '/dev/input/event16', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}\n{name: '/dev/input/mouse2', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}\n{name: '/dev/hidraw0', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}\n{name: '/dev/usb/hiddev3', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}\n{name: '/dev/input/event17', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}\n{name: '/dev/hidraw1', id_serial: 'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}{name: '/dev/media0', id_serial: 'SunplusIT_INC._Integrated_Camera'}\n{name: '/dev/video0', id_serial: 'SunplusIT_INC._Integrated_Camera'}\n"
```

so I am trying to parse it like this in my controller:

```
def index
   @devices = `./lib/scripts/get_serial.sh`.strip.gsub(" ","").split("\n")
end
```

and If I do `@devices[0]` the result is: `=> "{name:'/dev/input/event16',id_serial:'Logitech_USB_Receiver'}"`.

Finally, in the view:

```
<ul>
  <% @devices.each do |device| %>
    <li><%= device %> </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

displays all the devices, but If I do `<%= device.name %>` I get an error or `<%= device['name'] %>` I get the word "name".

My question is simple. Is there any better way to do this and process `:name` and `:id_serial` as typical variables (iterate the array and print them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
@devices = `./lib/scripts/get_serial.sh`.strip.gsub(" ","").split("\n")
```

Try to use:

```
@devices = `./lib/scripts/get_serial.sh`.split("\n").map {|hash_string| eval(hash_string)}
```

For more explanation you should check [How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object)

Comment: Unfortunately `device['name']` in the view shows empty/blank value.

Comment: @ChrisV. Why even should it? Try ``device[:name]``

Comment: If you don't explain this, I will resign from my job and become a baker or a garbage collector.

Comment: @ChrisV. Symbols are not Strings. Have a look at this, should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712706/ruby-symbols-vs-strings-in-hashes

Comment: I mean about the map and eval, not the symbols. Do you believe there's an easier way to accomplish this (the whole idea)?

Comment: @ChrisV. You don't need ``strip`` and delete spaces. By splitting you make an array from strings separated by ``\n``.  I'm not really into bash-scripting and the ``eval`` thing just came from the source I provided in my answer :)